# Applications locked by visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I don't know this is a common problem or just happens to me, but it's pretty odd.

When I open an application with visual studio I can't start it from somewhere else.

For example when I right click on a `aspx` file in a website project and click  on the `View in the browser` option while my default browser is firefox, I can't open an html file using firefox. On the other hand I can't start another instance of firefox.
Or when I try to edit a png file inside a project using photoshop (I run photoshop inside visual studio), photoshop is not available any more (nothing happens when I try to open another instance of it)

This doesn't happens in case I open this programs before I start them using visual studio!

Comment: Is Visual Studio started with administrative rights? Does it say "(Admin)" in the caption?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes it does. Is that the problem? how can I fix it? (starting vs with admin privileges and not having this problem)

Comment: I don't know if that is *a* problem or *the* problem, it was just a thought. Perhaps your UAE settings are too high, limiting things too much? I have no idea really but typically if you start a program that then detects that another process of itself is running and then tries to send data to it fails if one of them is administrative and the other is not.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen My UAE settings are in lowest level actually but yes you're right, it might be more than just visual studio.